# Edit scripts to hide File/Folder in fedora 14

Tags: linux, windows, gnome, open-source, fedora-14

I want to hide File/folders ending with "#" .
I used the '.' formula  but cant everytime rename 100s of files and folders ,i want the file /folder to be instantly hidden same like when we apply "." in 1 place of name of file/folder.
Im using gnome on fedora 14.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any language restraints?  I would recommend simply using a python script to do so; it is quite easy to rename files using the os module.

Code given your files are in a directory, dirName:

```
import os  
dirName = "/path/to/files" 
for filename in os.listdir(dirName):
    if not filename.startswith("."):
        if filename[-1] is "#":
            os.rename(filename,"." + filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the solution you're looking for is to get the source code for `ls`
and modify it not to show files whose names end with "#"
unless the `-a` or `-A` option has been specified.

Comment: i just want them to be  hidden from gnome/nautilus if its visible in terminals its ok.